# How to find the last column based on Row 4 using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to use a script to find the last column in the sheet (based on Row 4) and paste the name data from column A in the last column found by the script. This is my script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ()
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
  var aLast = ss.getRange((ss.getLastColumn()+1)+"4").getNextDataCell(direction.RIGHT).getColumn()
  var destRange = ss.getRange(4,aLast+1)

  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 5){
    if (e.value == 'Copy'){
      var source = ss.getRange("A7:A13")
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true})
      e.range.clearContent()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using `onEdit` function to trigger the script. Once the script is triggered, it should copy the data from Column A and paste it in Column D (Last column found) as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

However, seems like there are something wrong with the script. I think the problems come from `aLast` and `destRange` in the script. May I know how should I modify this two `var` so that the script can work properly? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var aLast = ss.getDataRange().getValues()[3].filter(String).length;
```

It will get you number of **not empty** cells in the 4th row.

If there are empty cells in the row it will need another solution.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for your reply. If I want it to be based on 7th row, what should I change? May I know what does `[3]` means in your code?

Comment: `getDataRange().getValues()` gives you 2D array with all rows and cells of the sheet. `[3]` is 4th 'row' of the 2D array. Beware, if the first three lines of your sheet are empty the number can be `[0]`. So it depends on your data. Probably it's safer to get the row more common way: `var aLast = ss.getRange(4, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].filter(String).length;`

Comment: For 7th row you need to change `[3]` by `[6]`

Comment: Sorry one last question, if I move the data in column A to Column O, what should I change for the parameter in `getRange`? I changed it to `var aLast = ss.getRange(7, 2, 2, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].filter(String).length;` but seems it is wrong

Comment: Firstly, for this case, you're need 15 (or 14) not empty cells in 7th row. This is the main point of the code, it takes the length of some row and uses it as a number of destination column. And secondly you don't need the ..2,2... It should be 1,1: `var aLast = ss.getRange(7, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].filter(String).length;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to move the resulting data one column to the left; can you try `var destRange = ss.getRange(4,aLast)` instead of `var destRange = ss.getRange(4,aLast+1)`?